# Exporting project from Blender to use in Android project

Tags: android, opengl-es

I starting a new android project using OpenGl ES 2, based on the example available in the offical page, and I want use some projects from Blender in this app. What format should I export this project in the Blender to facilitate its handling in the android project? And what library I should use to handle this file?

I want something which allow me use a class like that:

```
public class Triangle {

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
            "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
            "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
            "}";

    private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private final int mProgram;
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mColorHandle;
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    static float triangleCoords[] = {0.0f,  0.622008459f, 0.0f, -0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f, 0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f};
    private final int vertexCount = triangleCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

    float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 0.0f };

    public Triangle() {
        // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(triangleCoords.length * 4);
        // use the device hardware's native byte order
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
        vertexBuffer.put(triangleCoords);
        // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        // prepare shaders and OpenGL program
        int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // create OpenGL program executables

    }

    public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
        // Add program to OpenGL environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

        // Set color for drawing the triangle
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

        // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
        MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

        // Draw the triangle
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }
```

but instead of hard-code the values for the arrays of vertex, I read this values from the file (same for the colors and other components).

Each 3d project from Blender should have its class, and besides a `draw()` method, I want have other methods, like `walk()`, `jump()` etc, to associate to touch events.

Anyone can give a hint on this? I accept even indications of tutorials, since I am not able to find anything like this on Google (probably because I have no idea what search besides things like `android opengl tutorial`).

Comment: heres how you can load .obj files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316440/how-to-handle-index-buffer-in-opengl-es-1-1/22316797#22316797

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a game engine for Android that will import objects from Blender.  There has been a lot of development in this area recently, so I wrote this [article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/developing-mobile-game-graphics-for-intel-architecture-based-android-tablets-part-2) which summarizes them all.  Some are for Java, some C++, both open source and not.  There are a lot of good options it just depends on what is important to you.  The JMonkeEngine SDK, for example, is tightly coupled with Blender.  My favorite is the PowerVR SDK because it has its own object file format (POD) which is lightweight and customizable.